# c++11 Excel::Range^ and Excel::Worksheet->Columns()

Tags: excel, visual-studio, c++-cli

```cpp
#include "MyForm.h"
```

using namespace System;
using namespace Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel;

main() {
    Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::Application^ xlApp = gcnew Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::ApplicationClass();
    Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::Workbook^ xlBook = gcnew Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::WorkbookClass();
    Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::Worksheet^ xlSheet = gcnew Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::WorksheetClass();
    Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::Range^ xlRange = gcnew Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::WorksheetClass()->UsedRange;

`xlBook = xlApp->Workbooks->Open("ExSheet.xlsm", Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing);

for each(Worksheet^ Sheet in xlApp->Worksheets) { //Look through all sheets
    if (Sheet->Name == "Article") { //If Name = 'Article', then...
        Sheet->Select(true);        //   select sheet
        xlSheet = Sheet;
    }
}

xlRange = xlSheet->Columns(1);
xlRange = static_cast<Range^>(xlSheet)->Columns(1);
xlRange = safe_cast<Range^>(xlSheet)->Columns(1);
xlRange = dynamic_cast<Range^>(xlSheet)->Columns(1);}`

The last 4 commands (xlRange = ...) produce compiler errors:

At the line with the static_cast it says `invalid type conversion`. At all others: `Call to an object to a handle type without corresponding operator() or converter function to pointer-to-function-type`

I don't understand why. How do I get the columns into a Range^ object?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: At the line with the static_cast it says 'invalid type conversion'. At all others: 'Call to an object to a handle type without corresponding operator() or converter function to pointer-to-function-type

Comment: The C++ compiler is not very friendly to COM interop types that have a default property, particularly for the Range interface.  xlSheet->Columns->Item[1, Type::Missing] is the closest untested guess.  Really rather best to write this in C# instead.

Comment: No, that didn't work either: A value from type "System::Object ^" cannot be assigned to any entity from type "Microsoft::Office::Interop:Excel::Range ^"